# Get the repository default branch of a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm trying to use the GitHub API to get the default branch of a specified repository (`owner/repo`).

I didn't find any docs regarding that. To get all branches I use:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/owner/owner/branches
```

This outputs the following json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "docs",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "a3...",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/commits/a3..."
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "master",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "8c...",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/commits/8c..."
    }
  }
]
```

This is already useful because in my case, the default branch is either `master` (if exists) or `gh-pages`. But I still want to know what's the correct way to get the default branch of a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository object contains the `default_branch` field.

So, I can do:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo

{
  "id": 29...,
  "name": "repo",
  "full_name": "owner/repo",
  "owner": {...},
  "private": false,
  ...
  "default_branch": "master",
  ...
}
```

In this case, the `default_branch` has the `master` value.