# How do I programatically download the ZIP file for a GitHub repo's default branch?

Tags: github

I'm writing a PHP script that lets users enter a GitHub owner & repo name, and then it downloads a zip file from that repo.

GitHub allows linking directly to the download of the latest release for a repo: `/owner/name/releases/latest/download/name.zip` (see https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/linking-to-releases). So if a repo has a release, that works fine.

However, for repos without a release, I want to download from the default branch instead. GitHub provides a link for this (green 'Code' button > 'Download ZIP'), but that URL includes the branch name: `/owner/name/archive/[BRANCH].zip`.

Is there a way to link directly to the download for the *latest branch* without knowing what the branch might be called? For example, something like this hypothetical URL: `/owner/name/archive/latest.zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to read the default branch of the repository first [through GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669535/6309) (See [Get Repository](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository))

Once you have the default branch, you can use it to complete your [download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64279153/6309)

```
curl -L http://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<branch>.zip --output <branch>.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need the default branch name for something, you can do this in one call.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/zipball
```